# TALEND guess schema

Tags: talend

I have a problem to retrieve the schema of a tMSSQLinput component due to the fact that my selection from source DB contain a big XML column field that cause the crash of the guess schema operation. This is my simple query:
"SELECT * FROM myTable"

I wonder if is possible to retrieve the schema using the top clause TOP(1)
in order to just guess the schema, and than 
modify my query in my original format without the TOP clause.

The component will be able to retrieve all the data and not just the TOP(1) in the normal execution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the built-in schema option, the schema will remain the same until you press "guess schema" again.

So yes, if you change your query and don't change the schema it should work.

This can be easily tested using the `tLogRow` component.